# Change left bar thickness and color on charts.js line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart

Unless I'm mistake, this appears to be undocumented. Does anyone know if the far left bar colour on line charts can be changed?

[image]

It seems the first left bar is always darker than the grid lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of X and Y axis values. Chart.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383677/change-color-of-x-and-y-axis-values-chart-js)

Comment: I already saw that one. It's not the same. That method removes all grid lines (which includes the far left line), whereas I still want to keep them. The issue is for reasons unknown the far left line is darker than the rest. There's probably a way to change it's colour.

Answer (score 1):

you need zeroLineColor
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.8.0/axes/styling.html?h=zerolinecolor

```js
options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            zeroLineColor: '#fff' 
          },
          }
          ]}}
```

[ChartJS. Change axis line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958548/chartjs-change-axis-line-color)