# How to change the color of y axis labels in different color in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I want to change only selected label like November to April[image: For example]

Comment: you can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383677/change-color-of-x-and-y-axis-values-chart-js

Comment: Hi here is some old post from Stackoverflow [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383677/change-color-of-x-and-y-axis-values-chart-js)

Comment: hello @ArminLizde, I think my question is simple and understandable. anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be currently done in chartJS but with some code modifications it is possible.
Check out this [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2442)